# How jQuery build JSON array from multiple similar input fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, foreach

I have the below HTML code.  I would like to get the first address then for each `additionalAddress(x)` to build a nice array so that I can insert them into db.  This is all part of an jQuery `append` logic so the addresses can be unlimited.

```
<div class="controls" id="Locations">

<input class="span7" type="text" placeholder="Full Address" id="Address" style="margin: 0px 5px 5px 0;"><br>
<input class="span3" type="text" placeholder="(555) 555-5555" id="Phone" name="Phone" onkeyup="drawPhone(this);" style="margin: 0px 5px 5px 0;">
<input class="span4" type="text" placeholder="name@mybusiness.com" id="Email" onkeyup="drawEmail(this);"> <i class="icon-plus-sign" id="addAddress"></i>

<span id="additionalAddress1"><br><br>
    <input class="span7" type="text" placeholder="Full Address" id="Address1"><br><input class="span3" type="text" placeholder="(555) 555-5555" id="Phone1" name="Phone"><input class="span4" type="text" placeholder="name@mybusiness.com" id="Email1" > <i class="icon-minus-sign" id="removeAddress"></i></span>

<span id="additionalAddress2"><br><br><input class="span7" type="text" placeholder="Full Address" id="Address2"><br><input class="span3" type="text" placeholder="(555) 555-5555" id="Phone2" name="Phone"><input class="span4" type="text" placeholder="name@mybusiness.com" id="Email2" style="margin: -4px 0px 0 11px;"> <i class="icon-minus-sign" id="removeAddress"></i></span>

<span id="additionalAddress3"><br><br><input class="span7" type="text" placeholder="Full Address" id="Address3"><br><input class="span3" type="text" placeholder="(555) 555-5555" id="Phone3" name="Phone"><input class="span4" type="text" placeholder="name@mybusiness.com" id="Email3"> <i class="icon-minus-sign" id="removeAddress"></i></span>

</div>
```

Comment: Are all the `inline styles` really needed for that question? Additionally you have multiple `#Address`

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: You must not use an id for different elements. You can use the `name` or `class` attribute for this.

Comment: I will append the (x) to each ID.  How then can I proceed with solution. Updated question to reflect recommended comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
var address = new Array();
$("#Locations").find('span[id^="additionalAddress"]').each(function() {
    var temp = " " + $(this).find("input[id^='Address']").val();
    address.push(temp);
});
alert(address);
```

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/u5ULS/)

Comment: how would i also get the phone and email for respective address?

Answer (score 0):

If the number of additional addresses is fixed, you can use

```
[
    $("#Address").val(),
    $("#additionalAddress1 > input").val(),
    $("#additionalAddress2 > input").val(),
    $("#additionalAddress3 > input").val()
]
```

Assuming you removed the ids of the `input` elements inside the `additionalAddressX` spans.

[edit] If it is not fixed, you can use:

```
var addresses = [$("#Address").val()];
$("span[id^='additionalAddress'] > input[id^='Address']").each(function(i,e) {
    addresses.push($(e).val());
});
```

Assuming the `input` elements inside the `additionalAddressX` spans have ids like `AddressX`.

Comment: additional addresses will not be fixed

Comment: things are looking great. How would I include the respective email and phone number for the additional addresses and have an array to keep things "seperate"?

Comment: You can just use the latest block and replace the ids with the ones for the phone and email fields